# PHP: Delete Specific Column Value From SQL Table

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to delete a specific column value from an SQL table with php. The table looks like this:

```
             my_db 
------------------------------------------
 code       | user | email               |
------------------------------------------
 10314343   |  20  | example@example.com |
 13423434   |  22  | example@example.com |
 11342434   |  40  | example@example.com |
```

What I want to do is update the "code" value to empty on user "20". Here is what I have so far but it's not working:

```
$tbl_name = mydb;
$getcode = "10314343"


$updateCode = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET code ='', where code ='$getcode'";
$confirmUpdate = mysql_query($updateCode);
```

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO.

Comment: You have an extra `,` before `where`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should delete comma after `code=''`.
This one should work fine:

```
$updateCode = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET code ='' WHERE code ='$getcode'";
```

Comma used when you have to update several fields.
For example if yo want to update `code` and `email`, you should use sql query like this:

```
$updateCode = "UPDATE $tbl_name SET code ='', email='test@test.test' WHERE code ='$getcode'";
```

But after last component you should not paste comma

Answer (score 1):

The comma in your sql statement after `code=''` is not important. It is very important that you read about sql and understand it, especially its syntax else you might continue to go into these problem and lose time unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

To make it works remove `,` from your query.